# How to restore Azure Alert Rule that has been deleted

Tags: azure

I accidentally deleted an alert rule from my Azure account an now I want to recover that rule. So, is there any way to recover the Azure Alert Rule?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks similar to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d1c4799-4b17-48ab-b198-6bce99f8cb95/azure-alert-recovery?forum=hypervrecovmgr) MSDN thread. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you will be able to recover it, it would probably be quicker to recreate it. You would need to raise a support request to see if they can recover it.